# Updating field in a existing row Android

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-contentprovider

Hello I'm in a situation as follows upon receiving an item for storing on DB I have to execute insert if the row matching a unique field doesn't exists else update a particular field in the row. I tried this and I'm facing an Exception of

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column title is not unique (code 19)
```

How can I safely achieve the above scenarios without exception

Comment: is title column in primary column?

Comment: nope I have another primary column Title is just Unique @Jarvis

Answer (score 0):

You could use `UPDATE OR IGNORE`.

However if you are using the SQLiteDatabase `update` method, you cannot specify this.

You'd either use the `updateWithOnConflict` method. [SQLiteDatabase - updateWithOnConflict](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#updateWithOnConflict(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20int))

- with the conflict algorithm as `CONFLICT_IGNORE`.
- the method returns the number of rows updated.

Or you could pre-check for the uniqueness along the lines of

```
Cursor csr = dbhlpr.query(
    your_table,
    new String[]{your_column},
    your_column + "=?",
    new String[]{your_value_as_a_string},
    null,
    null,
    null
);
if (csr.getCount() < 1) {
    //.. do the update here using the `update` method
} else {
    //.. handle not able to insert as unique  here
}
csr.close();
```

Comment: What about [updateWithOnConflict()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#updateWithOnConflict(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20int))?